# Deleted Branch in Gitlab web interface. Trying to create a new branch with the same name gives the error "Branch already exists"

Tags: gitlab

We have a test branch which experienced a merge conflict. As this is a non prod branch, we deleted it in the web interface and decided to recreate again from the master branch. Trying to create a new branch (again, in the web interface) with the same name from master gives the error "Branch already exists".

If I clone the repo and run "git branch -a" the branch is not listed. I imagine there may be residual references to the branch remaining in a number of historic merge requests? Is there a way for me to create a branch with the same name here?

Comment: Based on what you've said, this sounds like a bug in GitLab. I'd suspect just what you do, that it keeps some hidden copies of the old branch name in some existing merge requests. Git itself seems to be working fine so you'll need a GitLab-specific solution.

Comment: What about creating the branch locally with what you need, then running `git push -f` to override the one that's possibly dangling on remote?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this one out. It was a strange bug in the Gitlab web interface. Was able to create the branch using git bash using these steps (in case anyone looks for this issue)

- git clone https://gitlab.com/yourgitrepo.git
- git checkout -b branchname branchtocreatefrom
- git push origin branchname

Never had this issue before. Maybe just a one off.

Comment: yeah, i believe the gitlab br deletion is asynchrone

Comment: @alxyok, *asynchronous